# Convert comma separated string to list items in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list like the following:

```
my_list = ['google', 'microsoft,facebook']
```

and I need to convert this into:

```
my_list = ['google', 'microsoft', 'facebook']
```

I tried doing it this way:

```
new_list = [item.split(',') for item in my_list]
flat_list = [item for sublist in new_list for item in sublist]
```

but this method involves unnecessary additional variables and multiple for loops. Is there a way we can make this easier?

Comment: @SatyamShankar Look more closely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by converting to the list to string and back to list as follows:

```
my_list = ['google','microsoft,facebook']

newList = ','.join(my_list).split(',')
```

Output:

```
['google', 'microsoft', 'facebook']
```

Answer (score 4):

The below is simple enough (make en empty list and `extend` it)

```
my_list = ['google','microsoft,facebook']
new_list = []
for x in my_list:
  new_list.extend(x.split(','))
print(new_list)
```

output

```
['google', 'microsoft', 'facebook']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one nested comprehension:

```
new_list = [x for item in my_list for x in item.split(',')]
```

Or use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

new_list = [*chain(*(item.split(',') for item in my_list))]
# or the more traditional
new_list = list(chain.from_iterable(item.split(',') for item in my_list))
```

And if you want to go all out with the functional utils:

```
from functools import partial

new_list = [*chain(*map(partial(str.split, sep=","), my_list))]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on doing it in-place, then you can do

```
for i,e in enumerate(my_list):
    my_list[i:i+1] = e.split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flat the list with `sum(mylist, [])`

```
l = ['google','microsoft,facebook']

ll = sum([s.split(',')  for s in l], [])

print(ll)
```

Output

```
['google', 'microsoft', 'facebook']
```

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to use `sum` to flatten a list. It has quadratic complexity as it builds ever growing new intermediate list objects.

Comment: @schwobaseggl the docs mentions some disadvantage only for string concatenation: 
__The preferred, fast way to concatenate a sequence of strings__ which is not the case of this question. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#sum)

Comment: The same holds for lists. Which is mentioned in the docs (*"a series of iterables"*). See e.g. [the graph in this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists#answer-40813764)

Comment: thanks for your remarks. I always ask myself on how should be interpreted the __consider to__ part of  __To concatenate a series of iterables, consider using itertools.chain().__

Comment: The docs mention strings explicitly because they have their own function (producing a string again, not just a lazy iterator). But the performance issues of `sum` for sequence-like objects (str, list, tuple, ...) are always the same.